# Python. sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer doesn't fit new columns at his previous position

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So, the my problem consists of that sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer doesn't fit new columns at his previous position.
I have a code to replace categorical data:

```
labelEncoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelEncoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelEncoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelEncoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
columnTransformer_1 = ColumnTransformer([('geographic and gender', OneHotEncoder(), [1, 2])], remainder='passthrough')
X = columnTransformer_1.fit_transform(X)
```

Is this normal work of

> remainder='passthrough'

It's just drop other columns after transformed columns?

So, how can I refactor this to get X with `previous [0]` column and then with `previous [1,2]`. Now I get X with wrong sequence: encoded columns goes at the begining of array, then other columns.